# Which browsers can automatically browse .eth domains?

Tags: ens, browsers, eth-domain

Ethereum Name Service (ENS) sells .eth domains, but browsers might require a gateway to view them. Which browsers can browse .eth domains automatically without gateway (e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Brave, Edge, etc)? And can we foresee browsers incorporating automatic access to them in their future versions? Is wider adoption amongst surfers (browsing, not registering) likely in the near-term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which browsers can browse .eth domains automatically without gateway

The last time I checked, the following browsers natively supported `.eth`.

(There may be others. There might also be overlap here with browsers that also support IPFS. Someone else can probably answer definitively.)

Desktop:

- Brave
- Unstoppable Browser

Mobile:

- Opera
- Status
- MetaMask (the mobile browser version)

> And can we foresee browsers incorporating automatic access to them in their future versions? Is wider adoption amongst surfers (browsing, not registering) likely in the near-term?

Difficult to answer without speculating.

Comment: Are .eth or .crypto domains more widely used? and which are more expensive as an investment. three-letter .eth domains sell for $700, while many three-letter .crypto domains have not yet been put on sale